# Criando matriz com a classe Scanner

Tags: java, java-8

Estou tentando prencher uma matriz 5x5 porem quando executo o FIM na entrada para encerrar, o código me retorna a matriz preenchida com a palavra FIM.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite");
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    String m[][] = new String[5][5];
    while (!s.equals("FIM")){
        System.out.println("Digite:");
        s = sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
                m[i][j] = s;
            }
        }
    }   
    sc.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(m[i][j]);
        }
    }   
  }     
 }
```

Saida do código:

```
 FIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIMFIM
```

saida desejada da matriz com todas as letras digitadas:

```
q w e r t a d r t h j a v a s p y t h o t r e f g
```

Comment: o código deve poder ser encerrado a qualquer momento ao digita FIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece quando vc digita qualquer coisa? Essa coisa é colocada em `s`, e em seguida vc percorre toda a matriz e coloca `s` em **todos** os elementos dela.

Se quer que cada elemento tenha um valor diferente, então a leitura tem que ficar dentro do *loop*:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String m[][] = new String[5][5];
principal: for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Digite algo (ou FIM para encerrar):");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if ("FIM".equals(s))
            break principal; // encerra o for externo
        m[i][j] = s;
    }
}
```

Ou seja, se digitar "FIM", ele já encerra o *loop* e não coloca o valor na matriz. Usei um *label* (`principal`, mas poderia ser qualquer nome) para que o `break` interrompa o `for` mais externo (sem isso, ele interromperia somente o `for` interno).

E no `for` interno usei `m[i].length`, já que a "matriz" na verdade é um array de arrays, e cada um pode ter um tamanho diferente (nesse caso não tem, mas de qualquer forma assim é mais garantido que sempre vou percorrer os tamanhos corretos).

---

Vale lembrar que se o *loop* for interrompido no meio, os elementos que não receberam nenhum valor serão `null`. Não ficou claro o que é para fazer nesse caso (se é para imprimir mesmo assim). Mas aí já outra história...

Comment: Obrigado amigo, me ajudou muito, esse é um trecho do código, minha intenção é criar uma matriz quadrada de caracteres e pesquisar uma palavra que se encontra  dentro dela, caso não se enconte retorna false.